# drawing squares using a recursive method with java

Tags: java, recursion, applet, paint

I am trying to write an applet that draws a main square and then uses a recursive method that draws smaller squares on the corners of the main square. I'm really confused on how to go about this. I have drawn the square with the others squares on its corners but i need to do this process recursively and thats where i get lost. I need to set a min side length so the recursive method knows when to stop. Here is my code.

```
 import javax.swing.JApplet;

 import java.awt.*;
public class LabC extends JApplet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
    g.drawRect(50, 100, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(25, 75, 50, 50);
    g.drawRect(125, 75, 50, 50);
    g.drawRect(125, 175, 50, 50);
    g.drawRect(25, 175, 50, 50);


}
}
```

Comment: I would start with writing another function, maybe call it `paintSquare()` that takes several other parameters that define the aspects that may change for each kind of square.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That's a good place to start. To add to that, I would also define the relationships between each square. One has an x dimension of 25 while the other has one of 125. There are patterns here that you should be noticing and taking advantage of in your recursive methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more or less what are you looking for

```
    public static class LabC extends JLabel {

    public void paintRecursiveWraper(Graphics g, int minW, int minH, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
        paintRecusive(g, minW, minH, x, y, w, h);
    }

    public void paintRecusive(Graphics g, int minW, int minH, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        if (h <= minH || w <= minW) {
            return;
        }

        int newW, newH;
        int newX, newY;
        newW = (int) (w * scaleFactor);
        newH = (int) (h * scaleFactor);

        // Bot Left Square
        newX = x;
        newY = y;
        g.drawRect(newX, newY, newW, newH);
        paintRecusive(g, minW, minH, newX, newY, newW, newH);
        // Bot Right Square
        newX = (int) (x + w * (1 - scaleFactor));
        newY = y;
        g.drawRect(newX, newY, newW, newH);
        paintRecusive(g, minW, minH, newX, newY, newW, newH);
        // Top Left Square
        newX = x;
        newY = (int) (y + h * (1 - scaleFactor));
        g.drawRect(newX, newY, newW, newH);
        paintRecusive(g, minW, minH, newX, newY, newW, newH);
        // Top Right Square
        newX = (int) (x + w * (1 - scaleFactor));
        newY = (int) (y + h * (1 - scaleFactor));
        g.drawRect(newX, newY, newW, newH);
        paintRecusive(g, minW, minH, newX, newY, newW, newH);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        paintRecursiveWraper(g, 10, 10, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);

    }
}
```

scaleFactor has to be between 0  and 1

Edited*

Comment: this is close to what I want. The only thing different that i'm trying to accomplish is that each new square needs to be drawn on the 4 corners of the main square.

Comment: @user3242607 Sounds like you should call `paintRecursive()` four times with different parameters. I suggest getting out a piece of paper and pencil to figure out formulas for the new values you need to pass to the recursive calls.

Comment: so the reduce factor would be something like 1/4?

Comment: I rename it. It was confusing. Its the new scaled square

Comment: but if i wanted the new squares to move to the next side would i have to call to recursive method again?

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood the question. Now it goes your way